# Seeking advice on improving performance with large IoT data on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, project, amazon-kinesis

I would appreciate some advice on a performance issue we are experiencing with our IoT data. Here's a brief overview of our situation:

Our IoT devices send data every 3 seconds, which is processed by a server and saved into a database.
The front-end application retrieves data from the database by calling the backend.
We are experiencing performance issues due to the large amount of data we have on the database and also the data we are receiving, and we want to avoid continually increasing server and database specs.
Here's some more information about our current structure and potential solutions we have considered:

Our Structure:

- Data sent by devices has about 60 values (mix of numbers and strings)
- IoT Core sends device data by a rule to an Elastic Beanstalk environment (PHP Laravel) that processes the data and saves it to an RDS database (Postgres)
- Data is saved in one table with added indexes for improved performance
- Users access data through an Amplify application (Angular) that calls the backend, which retrieves data from the database

  [image]

TimescaleDB: We have benchmarked TimescaleDB but have found that it does not solve our issue of having to continually increase server and database specs to handle the large amount of data.

Potential Solutions:

- Storing data in small files (CSV or JSON) on Amazon S3: The server will receive data and, depending on the date, save it to a specific file every hour. The backend will generate temporary links for users to access the data. This solution will take load off the server and database.

  [image]
- Like the previous solution but instead of the server we use a Lambda function to handle data from IoT devices and saving it directly to S3 which will reduce the load on the server.

  [image]
- Same as the last solution but using Kinesis instead of Lambda to handle IoT data, allowing us to retain data for a short period of time for quick access and then saving it to S3. This solution also allows for potential analytics on the data in the future.

  [image]

We are looking for advice on these potential solutions, as well as any other suggestions or feedback that you may have. We want to improve performance without increasing costs, so any input you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Youssef.